# if statement against each item in a list

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to do something like the following in python, but i am getting an invalid syntax error:

```
network_n = 192.168.38
octate_n = network_n.split(".")
if (len(o) [for o in octate_n]) == 3:
```

But when i am run it, i get:

```
if (len(o) [for o in octate_n]) == 3:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My problem is with the if statement, what is wrong there ?

I admit that i have a rough idea about the difference between the `()` and the `[]` in the if statement, so i would be glad that you give me a short explanation about it.

Comment: did you mean `network_n = "192.168.38"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
if(all(len(o) == 3 for o in octate_n)):
    # do stuff
```

About your seconds question, `[o for o in octate_n]` creates a list that consists of all items in `octate_n` (this is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)), while `(o for o in octate_n)` creates a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) that will yield all the items of `octate_n` (this is called a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can tell you what's wrong with the syntax of your conditional: you at least need to include `len(o)` inside the brackets.

```
[len(o) for o in octate_n]
```

This structure, `[expr for var in list]`, is called a list comprehension and it's a shorthand for "evaluate `expr` for each element of `list`, with `var` set to the element, and make a new list of the results." In your original code you didn't have any `expr` which is why Python was complaining.

Now, even if you fix that, you wind up with

```
if [len(o) for o in octate_n] == 3:
```

which still has the problem that you are comparing a list to a number. While you can technically do that, it probably doesn't mean what you expect: a list will never be equal to a number, because they are different objects. It's not quite clear what you were trying to do, though. If you wanted to find whether *all* the elements of the list have length equal to 3, you would write

```
if all([len(o) == 3 for o in octate_n]):
```

or, more efficiently,

```
if all(len(o) == 3 for o in octate_n):
```

Note the absence of the square brackets in the later statement. This is because you don't actually need to make a *list* out of the results; you just need to be able to go through them one at a time and check if they're all true. Omitting the brackets is what indicates this to Python. (You can only do this inside parentheses.)

Answer (score 0):

You using len on single element of the list. Emm.. no.. you use len(o) on element that is not defined. 
Use:

```
if (len(octate_n) == 3:
```

Sorry, got your idea. If you want to check that all of the elements of the list are 3 chars long - use "all" as in answer below.

Comment: This is not what the OP intends. He wants to check if each part of the IP-address has three digits. Also, [unmatched parenthesis](http://xkcd.com/859/)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is. Here are a bunch of possibilities:

**If you want to return all the members of `octate_n` that have a length of 3:**

```
with_len_3 = [o for o in octate_n if len(o) == 3]
```

---

**If you want to make sure there are 3 elements in `octate_n`:**

```
if len([o for o in octate_n]) == 3:
    # do stuff
```

*which is the same as*

```
if len(octate_n) == 3:
    # do stuff
```

---

**If you want to make sure that all of the elements in `octate_n` are of length 3:**

```
if( all(len(o) == 3 for o in octate_n) ):
    # do stuff
```

*this is a cleaner, faster version of:*

```
if len([o for o in octate_n if len(o) == 3]) == len(octate_n):
    # do stuff
```