# If statement with composite condition to validate condition against each item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600567/if-statement-against-each-item-in-a-list) but the answers don't seem to apply to my issue.

Here is my code:

```
y = 3
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

if y != 0 or y != list1:
    print("y is not in range")
else:
    print(y)
```

It keeps printing `y is not in range`.

My goal is to check if `y` does **not** equal to `0` **or** if `y` does not equal to any item in the list.

---

I understand that the above `or` should be an `and`, I'm specifically interested in how to check in the condition of `y` being contained in the list.

Comment: Do you understand looping? Look up `for` loops. And this always prints that line because `y != list1` will always be true. A list will never be equal to a number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to check that `y` is different from `0` **AND** not in the list:

```
if y != 0 and y not in list1:
```

Using `or` means that *one* of the conditions is sufficient, so since `y != 0` it returns `True` without going to `y != list1` which would always return `False` because an `int` is not a `list`, you have to use `in` in that case.

---

If you really want to use an `or` then you what you want:

```
if not (y == 0 or y in list1):
    print('y not in range')
else:
    print(y)
```

Rememer the De Morgan laws:

```
not (y == 0 or y in list1) == (not y == 0) and (not y in list1) == y != 0 and y not in list1
```

Comment: While this is the right answer for this particular problem, the title of the question suggests a slightly different question than the one in the body.

Comment: @Carcigenicate So edit the title? Titles and questions frequently mismatch and I have never seen any suggestion that we should ignore the question and answer the title instead.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The title should be a summary of the question. The question *is the body*. If the don't match the title should be edited to match the body. I'll later edit the question to make it clearer and try to find a better title.

Comment: @Bakuriu, while your answer is right, I believe the portion for `TypeError` may be incorrect for this instance. As it only applies to `<, <=, >, >=` [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

Comment: @CoryShay Yeah, you are right. I was thinking of `<` and then forgot about it. Fixed.

Comment: thank you! the `not in` was the keyword/s I was looking for.

Comment: @Bakuriu the change in the title does not seem to reflect what my question originally is about and it will make it more difficult for others to find such a question with such an answer in the future. I wanted to ask about: "if conditional statement against each item in a list". the part where I used "or" was just a flaw in my logic, so please change the title to reflect more about "y not in list1" and less about the flawed logic of my 'or'. thanks

Comment: @coolpy I don't think so. Your question was. "why does this code always print X" and the answer was that it did that specifically because you used `or`. If you used `and` with the same condition it would always have taken the second branch and never the first one. In any case, since you wanted to ask about `in` your question is a duplicate and I've marked it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question asked in the title, you can write something like

```
true if condition else false for y in list1
```

to check `condition` for every element `y` in the list `list1`.
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) a useful link.

Otherwise @Bakuriu response is correct.